# I am developing windows phone 8.1 application and using Dispatcher.RunAsync method but its not executing second time

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing windows phone 8.1 application and using Dispatcher.RunAsync method but its executed only once , when control again comes to same Dispatcher, Code inside Dispatcher not executing.

Answer (score 0):

You can check when the control comes the second time to dispatcher whether the Dispatcher has thread access or not. In that case it might not execute the code inside.
You can use the following property of dispatcher to check that.

```
 public bool HasThreadAccess { get; }
```

This property inside CoreDispatcher class.

Comment: if my dispatcher do not  have thread access then what should i can do? any way to solve this?

Comment: That is because your UI thread is hogged by some other code. One way is to set the dispatcher priority to HIgh but it might not work. Other wise its difficult to say without seeing the code.